# Elastic search (Kibana) - intersect between boolean results

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql, kibana

I am facing a problem in Kibana how to correctly filter a data. Basically my aim is to filter PASSED or FAILED tests from the following data structure.

```
{
 "_index":"qa-reporting-2020-04",
 "_type":"qa-reporting",
 "_id":"456.0",
 "_version":1,
 "_score":null,
 "_source":{
  "TestId":"CXXX01",
  "TestStatus":0,
  "Issues":[
  ],
  "MetaData":{
     "TestName":"Test1",
     "LastException":null,
     "DurationMs":1980.5899000000002,
     "Platform":{
        "BrowserName":"chrome",
        "OS":"windows",
        "OsVersion":"10"
     },
     "Categories":[
        "Cat1",
        "Cat2",
        "CXXX01"
     ],
     "Priority":null,
     "TestStatusStr":"Passed",
     "JobName":"My-Demo/dev/ServerJob1",
     "Logs":"PASS  - Passed - CXXX01",
     "SuiteName":"Tests.ServerTests",
     "LastMessage":"PASS  - Passed - CXXX01: \n",
     "Environment":"dev"
  }
 }
}
```

The problem is that during a time (day), the logs will have several entries (e.g. the test failed and later in the same day the test passed). I have an aggregation query that gives me both results which is not desired. I want to have a result returning the intersection so the report will contain either failed/passed tests.

Here is my query (I am begginer) which gives me aggregation for a specific test that failed and passed.

```
GET qa-reporting-*/_search
{"size": 0, 
 "query": {
  "bool": {
  "must": [
    {
      "match": {
        "MetaData.Environment": "dev"
      }
    },
    {
      "match": {
        "TestId": "CXXX01"
      }
    },
    {
      "range": {
        "Created": {
          "gte": "now-0d/d"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
},
"aggs": {
"tests": {
  "terms": {"field": "MetaData.TestStatusStr.keyword"}
  }
 }
}
```

It returns the following (excerpt from the entire object)

```
"aggregations": {
"tests": {
  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
  "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
  "buckets": [
    {
      "key": "Passed",
      "doc_count": 10
    },
    {
      "key": "Failed",
      "doc_count": 1
    }
  ]
 }
}
```

As above mentioned how to get the intersection between failed/passed tests during a specific date time? Is it possible to do it in Kibana or it needs to be solved on a script level outside of it?

Currently my report looks like this:

```
 DateTime        | TestId | Status
 Apr 24,12:00    | CXXX01 | Failed
 Apr 24,15:00    | CXXX01 | Passed
```

Wanted report will be only the intersection of the above status

```
 Apr 24   | CXXX01 | Failed
```

or

```
 Apr 24   | CXXX01 | Passed
```

So the latest result will have more weight I think.

Comment: If we assume that the TestName is the key, you need the final state? e.g. ||| TestA -> failed at 13.00, passed at 14.00 -> Passed ||| -- |||
TestB -> failed at 16.00, passed at 17.00, failed at 18.00 -> Failed |||
failed (1), passed (1). Is that correct?

Comment: I re-redefined my requirement. See above. Basically if the test passed in the morning and evening then result will be passed. I do not want to display test failed in the final report. And vice versa, if passed and then failed I am concerned about failure.

Comment: You need latest entry of each test?

Comment: @jaspreetchahal I guess it would be the solution. Let's say if I would like to see results of a test for 3 previous days, I think the most recent result from each day will be the desired. Because from top of my head it would be useless to do intersection, right?

Comment: @jaspreetchahal Thank you very much. I did not know about the top_hits. Good stuff to learn and start using it. Your answer works like a charm. By the way, not sure a new thread needs to be created here, but is there a possibility to do the intersection. Like for example failed & passed => failed. In SQL it is likely possible, but not sure in Kibana. Cheers

Comment: @Michal didn't get your question. Can you add a sample output.

Comment: @jaspreetchahal Your query gives me top_hits results per each day. As from the title of this post, how the query should look like if I want to see one test result from both days. I want to have just one result from those 2 days which will be intersection. It means if both results will be passed then final result will be passed. If either of those days will be failed then the result is failed.

`datetime | result`
`Apr24     | failed`
`Apr23     | passed`
=> `overall results  is failed`

`datetime | result`
`Apr24     | passed`
`Apr23     | passed`
=> `overall results  is passed`

Comment: @Michal In aggregation you cannot loop over buckets and perform operation on it. This should be handled in client side

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212548/discussion-between-michal-and-jaspreet-chahal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken data for two days. Two entries for each day. Last entry for day 1 is "Failed" and latest entry for day 2 is "Passed"

**Data:**

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index19",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "QKlosXEBuBOc-UQkKecO",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "TestId" : "CXXX01",
          "TestStatus" : 0,
          "Issues" : [ ],
          "Created" : "2020-04-23T01:00:00",
          "MetaData" : {
            "TestName" : "Test1",
            "LastException" : null,
            "DurationMs" : 1980.5899000000002,
            "Platform" : {
              "BrowserName" : "chrome",
              "OS" : "windows",
              "OsVersion" : "10"
            },
            "Categories" : [
              "Cat1",
              "Cat2",
              "CXXX01"
            ],
            "Priority" : null,
            "TestStatusStr" : "Passed",
            "JobName" : "My-Demo/dev/ServerJob1",
            "Logs" : "PASS  - Passed - CXXX01",
            "SuiteName" : "Tests.ServerTests",
            "LastMessage" : "PASS  - Passed - CXXX01: \n",
            "Environment" : "dev"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index19",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "QalosXEBuBOc-UQkieeR",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "TestId" : "CXXX01",
          "TestStatus" : 0,
          "Issues" : [ ],
          "Created" : "2020-04-23T10:00:00",
          "MetaData" : {
            "TestName" : "Test1",
            "LastException" : null,
            "DurationMs" : 1980.5899000000002,
            "Platform" : {
              "BrowserName" : "chrome",
              "OS" : "windows",
              "OsVersion" : "10"
            },
            "Categories" : [
              "Cat1",
              "Cat2",
              "CXXX01"
            ],
            "Priority" : null,
            "TestStatusStr" : "Failed",
            "JobName" : "My-Demo/dev/ServerJob1",
            "Logs" : "PASS  - Passed - CXXX01",
            "SuiteName" : "Tests.ServerTests",
            "LastMessage" : "PASS  - Passed - CXXX01: \n",
            "Environment" : "dev"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index19",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "QqlosXEBuBOc-UQkoue4",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "TestId" : "CXXX01",
          "TestStatus" : 0,
          "Issues" : [ ],
          "Created" : "2020-04-24T10:00:00",
          "MetaData" : {
            "TestName" : "Test1",
            "LastException" : null,
            "DurationMs" : 1980.5899000000002,
            "Platform" : {
              "BrowserName" : "chrome",
              "OS" : "windows",
              "OsVersion" : "10"
            },
            "Categories" : [
              "Cat1",
              "Cat2",
              "CXXX01"
            ],
            "Priority" : null,
            "TestStatusStr" : "Failed",
            "JobName" : "My-Demo/dev/ServerJob1",
            "Logs" : "PASS  - Passed - CXXX01",
            "SuiteName" : "Tests.ServerTests",
            "LastMessage" : "PASS  - Passed - CXXX01: \n",
            "Environment" : "dev"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index19",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Q6losXEBuBOc-UQkwecl",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "TestId" : "CXXX01",
          "TestStatus" : 0,
          "Issues" : [ ],
          "Created" : "2020-04-24T11:00:00",
          "MetaData" : {
            "TestName" : "Test1",
            "LastException" : null,
            "DurationMs" : 1980.5899000000002,
            "Platform" : {
              "BrowserName" : "chrome",
              "OS" : "windows",
              "OsVersion" : "10"
            },
            "Categories" : [
              "Cat1",
              "Cat2",
              "CXXX01"
            ],
            "Priority" : null,
            "TestStatusStr" : "Passed",
            "JobName" : "My-Demo/dev/ServerJob1",
            "Logs" : "PASS  - Passed - CXXX01",
            "SuiteName" : "Tests.ServerTests",
            "LastMessage" : "PASS  - Passed - CXXX01: \n",
            "Environment" : "dev"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Query:** I have used [date_histogram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html) to create bucket of each day and [top_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html)
 aggregation to get last document of that day

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "MetaData.Environment": "dev"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "TestId": "CXXX01"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "Created": {
              "gte": "now-3d/d"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "daily":{
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "Created",
        "interval": "day"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "last_result": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "_source": ["MetaData.TestStatusStr"], 
            "sort": [
              {"Created":"desc"}]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Result:**

```
"aggregations" : {
    "daily" : {
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2020-04-23T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key" : 1587600000000,
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "last_result" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 2,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : null,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "index19",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "QalosXEBuBOc-UQkieeR",
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "MetaData" : {
                      "TestStatusStr" : "Failed"
                    }
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    1587636000000
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2020-04-24T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key" : 1587686400000,
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "last_result" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 2,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : null,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "index19",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "Q6losXEBuBOc-UQkwecl",
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "MetaData" : {
                      "TestStatusStr" : "Passed"
                    }
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    1587726000000
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```