# Elastic search (Kibana) - how to display conditional report

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, dsl

This question is a follow up on the previous question about how to get top_hits in Kibana. [Elastic search (Kibana) - intersect between boolean results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61417564/elastic-search-kibana-intersect-between-boolean-results).
Now my concern is how to get one report from last three days. See the screenshot bellow from Kibana. Instead of displaying report for all previous days I would like to have one report that will display the final results based on the following logic.

```
Failing scenario:
Now-2d | TestA | Failed 
Now-1d | TestA | Failed
Now    | TestA | Failed
=> TestA | Failed

Passing scenario
If TestA failed less than three times then display Passed
```

[image: sample report]

Is something like this achievable in Kibana? I do not want to implement a solution out of Kibana (.NET,Java,..) that will send a query to Elastic search for last three days, do some magic logic and display a chart.